# jQuery how to POST/AJAX on a page loaded with the load() function without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I decided to load the content of urls into a content div with jQuery and ajax, was pretty simple to do using .load();

Works really nicely and is nippy as hell. Now i'm looking at this content and realising it has a multitude of forms which when submitted don't submit within the content div I made.

The only way I can think of streamlining this process is making a dirty great big JS file to handle each form submission dynamically.

Consider there are many forms in this app i'm trying to think of a nice way of submitting forms without page reload within the content div, but keeping some sort of structure to the files behind it at least.

Any suggestions would be hugely welcomed.

As an idea of what i'm doing at a basic level take a look at the code snippet below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a').bind('click', function(e) {        
    $("#content").html('<img src="images/ajax-loader-small.gif">');   
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      $('#content').load(url); // load the html response into a DOM element
      e.preventDefault(); // stop the browser from following the link       
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax(), $.post(), $.get(), $.postJSON(), $getJSON()
```

Are your friendly functions in this scenario I think.
What your basically gonna do is create a click function for your form's existing submit buttons..

```
$('#mysubmitbutton').live('click', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('url/to/post/data', $('#form').serialize(), function(data)
    {
         alert('post made');
    }, 'json');
});
```

now of course it gets much more elaborate if you want it to, such as what if my fields are blank, what if the php errors, what if all is good and I want to send it to a new page now or clear the fields, etc.. all of which is possible with these functions, but to cover everything would take a long time, this concept is just to give you a push out the gate, and we are always happy to help you further here when you run into any issues with the function of choice from the above list/example.

Comment: Thanks for responding Chris - sort of compounds what I was thinking. I'm most worried creating a uniform method to handle these form submissions across say 50 or so forms is going to be tough. I don't want to add too much extra work to the project by having to handle client and server side.

Comment: While the above is a means of compacting it down as much as possible, there will always be a need on a per form basis to do something. My suggestion would be create a unique identifier for each submit button at the least, then pack a JS file filled with something similar to the above for the forms that need there special attention. then include this particular javascript file with all views that have a form, this way at the very least your not running circles for various files to change something here there and every where for one thing. It will all at the least be consolidated in one file.

Comment: I've worked for several large enterprises, building both in house applications (SaaS products) as well as web based apps, and this is generally how its done to one extent or another. Just saying so you don't feel super obligated to have some super condensed down code to run everything from one function. As some people will lead you to believe is the only way to do it, grant it, if you plan some functionality just right you can make some nicely reuseable things that scale for many applications but sometimes, theres just no better way then the way some would say less desired.

Comment: Well I have to say thats re-assuring. Thanks alot for the advice! I'm going to be consolidating a large existing legacy code base into a method similar to this, whilst hopefully converting into a framework (of some description). One thing I will need to be quite conscious of is how to handle failures in loading content etc. As of course the user would just think nothing is happening if jQuery failed to load the content. Although i'm pretty sure jQuery has callbacks for fail and success :-)